# How to display different infos when hovering over an image with mouse in matlab guide?

Tags: matlab, tooltip, matlab-guide

I have an image that consists of several segments with different labels. The labels are color coded. Does someone know how I can tell matlab to display the current label in a text box when hovering over it?
I would basically need to display different text boxes depending on where on the image the mouse cursor is placed.

I found some examples using `tooltip` but these apply only to buttons and not to images depending on the exact pixel location that the mouse is hovering over.

Here is an example image:
[image]

Comment: Do you intend the displayed information to follow the mouse as it moves? Or in a fixed location somewhere in the GUI, or centred in each segment?

Comment: Both would be fine. The info should just depend on the (x,y) position of the image that the mouse is currently hovering above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you mean by "several labels", but I think you want to be able to display a popup edit over an image, I think the following does what you want:

```
function hoverTest
  % create a figure (units normalized makes updating the position easier in the callback
  f = figure ( 'units', 'normalized' );
  % create an axes
  ax = axes ( 'parent', f );
  % load some data for plotting
  c = load ( 'clown' );
  % plot the data
  image ( c.X, 'parent', ax );
  % create a uipanel to host the text we will display
  uip = uipanel ( 'parent', f, 'position', [0 0 0.18 0.05], 'visible', 'off' );
  % create a text control to display the image info
  txt = uicontrol ( 'style', 'edit', 'parent', uip, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0 0 1 1] );
  % assign the callback for when the mouse moves
  f.WindowButtonMotionFcn =  @(obj,event)updateInfo(f,uip,ax,txt,c.X);
end
function updateInfo ( f, uip, ax, txt,img )
  % update the position of the uipanel - based on the current figure point (normalized units)
  set ( uip, 'Position', [f.CurrentPoint uip.Position(3:4)] );
  % Check to see if the figure is over the axes (if not hide)
  if ax.CurrentPoint(1,1) < min(ax.XLim) || ...
     ax.CurrentPoint(1,1) > max(ax.XLim) || ...
     ax.CurrentPoint(1,2) < min(ax.YLim) || ...
     ax.CurrentPoint(1,2) > max(ax.YLim)
   uip.Visible = 'off';
  else
    % show the panel
    uip.Visible = 'on';
    % get the current point
    cp = round(ax.CurrentPoint);
    % update the text string of the uicontrol
    txt.String = sprintf ( 'img(%i,%i) = %i', cp(1,1), cp(1,2), img(cp(1,2),cp(1,1) ) );
  end

end
```

Comment: Seems to work, thank you :). Although I have Matlab R2013a so I have to call `handle()` explicitly on every object  in order to get its handle. Eg `ax = handle(ax)`

Comment: Actually do you also know how to use a small yellow textbox (like tooltip) to display the text in it or is that not possible ?

Comment: A simple way is just to set the background color of the txt control to be yellow.

Comment: Your example is working fine. However I'm using matlab guide, as shown in the picture above. I cannot create new figures, axes... Do you know how I can get the corresponding handles within matlab guide?

Comment: I never use guide - but everything should be in your handles structure - probably `handles.figure` and `handles.axes`.  You can still create other `uicontrols` to create the tooltip though.